# Finding Cheapest n-Path

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, directed-acyclic-graph, shortest-path

Given a weighted directed acyclic graph, how can I find the cheapest path from an `Origin Vertex` to a `Destination Vertex` which goes through exactly `n` vertices?

Is there an efficient algorithm which accomplishes this? I know that I could use BFS to find all the possible paths between them, then filter that to get only the ones which are `n` long, and then sort them by cost. However, I would like to know if there's an algorithm which does not need to consider all possible paths to generate the result.

Comment: What do you mean by efficient?

Comment: I'll edit my question to clarify. I mean an algorithm which does not have to consider all possible paths, only n-paths, in order to generate the result.

Comment: The problem seems to be $\mathsf{NP}$-complete, since it reduces to Hamiltonian path in a DAG (just take $n=|V|$). May be this link can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124844/algorithm-for-finding-a-hamilton-path-in-a-dag

Comment: @PeterShor Forgive me if I'm being stupid here, but wouldn't it be impossible to visit the same node twice in a DAG? I think there would be a cycle if you could ever go back to somewhere you already visited, so it wouldn't be acyclical.

Comment: Of course it would. I didn't notice the DAG restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are given a weighted directed acyclic graph with source $s$ and destination $t$ and you want to find the shortest path from $s$ to $t$ with length exactly $n$ , this can be done easily with dynamic programming. Let $F(v,k)$ denote the shortest path from $v$ to $t$ with length exactly $k$ , we have
 $F(t , k) = \begin{cases}
  0 \ \ \ \ \text{ if }k = 0\\    
  +\infty \ \text{if } k > 0    
\end{cases}$.
 and
$F(v , k) = \begin{cases}
  \infty \text{ if }k = 0\\    
  \min_{u \in N^{+}(v)} F(u , k-1)+W(v,u)   
\end{cases}$ 
Solution is $F(s,n)$.

Comment: Thanks! But is this method any more efficient than the one I posted in my original question? It seems like this will try every possible path from `s` to `t` in order to generate the answer.

Comment: @Reubend: it doesn't try every possible path. If there are two paths (b,c,t) and (b,d,t) from b to t, and (b,c,t) is longer, then it never worries about (a,b,c,t).